# How to purge data older than 6 months?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, delete-row

I have an SQL job that I created to purge the data older than 6 months retention period, but it is deleting the data from the table.

Here is what my script looks like:

```
DECLARE @Retention_Date DATETIME = DATEADD(MM, -6, GETDATE()) 

PRINT 'Step Start: Purge'

DELETE FROM DBA.PD_WaitStats            WHERE Created_On > @Retention_Date

DECLARE @StepEndTime DATETIME = GETDATE()
PRINT 'Step End Time : ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @StepEndTime, 109)
GO
```

How do I delete data older than x months ago?

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:-

```
DELETE FROM DBA.PD_WaitStats WHERE Created_On < @Retention_Date
```

Note the less than symbol.  You want to delete older data, right?

Comment: arent there performance penalties when deleting the records like this, isnt partitioning by date range a better option when it comes to larger set of data